# node.js forever stops after some time

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, forever

I have a small node.js + socket.io app, that should be up all the time, but it somehow stops over some time, I have to start it again and again, sometimes must kill the process

`$ killall node`

and then start it

`$ forever start node.js`

and this is the output

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay
up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: /path/node.js
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You could have errors in your node app that put it in a bad state.  Nobody here can solve this for you.  You will have to instrument your node app with lots of debug code and figure out what is going on with it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, now at least I know where to start

Comment: Have you looked into PM2 at all? It's similar to forever but it will save all of your logs, and even errors for you. It will show ram usage, amount of restarts, uptime, etc.. I would really recommend it if possible.

Comment: @Nick_Core have you got the solution? which is given by TylerWaite17